# Execute multiple Powershell commands from C# containing variable

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a powershell script that I would like to run from C#. The contents of the script are:

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mysite/"
$w.UseClaimsAuthentication = 1
$w.Update()
$w.ProvisionGlobally()
$w.MigrateUsers($True)
```

and is used to set a site to Claims Based Authentication. I know how to execute a multiple commands from C# but am not sure how to run the entire script taking into account the variable $w.

```
PowerShell OPowerShell = null;
Runspace OSPRunSpace = null;
RunspaceConfiguration OSPRSConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException OExSnapIn = null;
//Add a snap in for SharePoint. This will include all the power shell commands for SharePoint
PSSnapInInfo OSnapInInfo = OSPRSConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell", out OExSnapIn);
OSPRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(OSPRSConfiguration);
OPowerShell = PowerShell.Create();
OPowerShell.Runspace = OSPRunSpace;
Command Cmd1 = new Command("Get-SPWebApplication");
Cmd1.Parameters.Add("http://mysite/");
OPowerShell.Commands.AddCommand(Cmd1);
// Another command
// Another command
OSPRunSpace.Open();
OPowerShell.Invoke();
OSPRunSpace.Close();
```

How would I execute all of the commands either by adding them as separate commands or saving the script to file and reading it in for execution? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`AddScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to add a string containing a script:

```
OPowerShell.Commands.AddScript("@
 $w = Get-SPWebApplication ""http://mysite/""
 $w.UseClaimsAuthentication = 1
 $w.Update()
 $w.ProvisionGlobally()
 $w.MigrateUsers($True)
");
```

You can add multiple script excerpts to the pipeline before invoking it. You can also pass parameters to the script, like:

```
OPowerShell.Commands.AddScript("@
 $w = Get-SPWebApplication $args[0]
 ...
");
OPowerShell.Commands.AddParameter(null, "http://mysite/");
```

You can also have a look at [Runspace Samples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

--- Ferda